# Como adicionar envio via SMTP no phpMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Bom dia,

Tenho o seguinte código para enviar um e-mail via PHPMailer.

```
<?php

    $GetPost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $Erro      = true;
    $Tipo      = $GetPost['tipo'];
    $Nome      = $GetPost['nome'];
    $Email     = $GetPost['email'];
    $Telefone  = $GetPost['telefone'];
    $Cargo     = $GetPost['cargo'];
    $Curriculo = $_FILES['curriculo'];
    $Mensagem  = $GetPost['mensagem'];

    include_once 'PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';
    include_once 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    $Mailer = new PHPMailer;
    $Mailer->CharSet = "utf8";
    $Mailer->SMTPDebug = 3;

    $Mailer->FromName = "Jogo Digital";
    $Mailer->From = "envio@adaoimoveis.com.br";
    $Mailer->AddAddress("leo@jogo.digital");
    $Mailer->IsHTML(true);
    $Mailer->Subject = "Novo currículo \"Trabalhe Conosco\" - {$Nome}";
    $Mailer->AddAttachment($Curriculo['tmp_name'], $Curriculo['name']);
    $Mailer->Body = "
    Novo currículo enviado por {$Nome}<br />
    Tipo: {$Tipo}<br /><br>
    <b>Dados:</b><br /><br>
    Email: {$Email}<br>
    Telefone: {$Telefone}<br>
    Cargo: {$Cargo}<br>
    Mensagem: {$Mensagem}<br>
    Curriculo: {$Curriculo}
    ";

    if(!$Mailer->Send()){
        echo "<script>alert('Não foi possível enviar, tente novamente!');window.history.back();</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Curriculo enviado com sucesso!');window.history.back();</script>";
    }
```

O que devo inserir neste código para que o envio seja feito por smtp? Pois do jeito que está agora, todos os e-mails estão caindo no SPAM.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mail->isSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP    
$mail->Host = 'mail.dominio.com.br'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'sites@dominio.com.br'; // Usuario
$mail->Password = 'senhadeemail123'; // Senha
```

Comment: Poderia discorrer mais sobre sua resposta? Acredito que traria mais qualidade a ela e ao site em geral.